# How to transfer data from a python scrip to a column in powerbi

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, transfer

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

x = dataset.loc[0:47,"Année"]
y = dataset.loc[0:47,"Capex (M€)"]

Capex_brut = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
Capex_lissés = savgol_filter(y, 48, 4) # window size 50, polynomial order 3

x_new = np.linspace(2023, 2070, 300)
plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(x_new,Capex_brut(x_new),color = 'black')
plt.plot(x, Capex_lissés, color = 'green')
plt.legend(['nuage', 'linear', 'lissés'], loc='best')
plt.show()

# I try with this lien below but unsuccefull
dataset.loc[0:47,"Lissage"] = Capex_lissés
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This script is written directly in PowerBI (not in powerquery) and after using  savgol_filter, i would like to create a new column in my table with the result of the filter : "Capex_lissés".
In others terms, how to import data from the script to tables in PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can write any scripts in Power BI, you will need to install the latest version of Python from the [Python website](https://www.python.org/).

Once you have installed Python, you need to specify the correct Python file path in Power BI Desktop. From the ribbon, select ‘File’, then ‘Options and settings’, and then select ‘Options’. In the list of global options, look for ‘Python scripting’. This is where you will need to find the directory that contains the Python distribution.

To use Python scripts in Power BI:

First, In the Home tab, select `‘Get data’` to bring up the full list of data connections. Select the ‘Other’ category and find `‘Python script’` on the list. This will allow you to write a Python script to import a dataset.

And then, A dialogue box will pop up where you can enter your Python code. Power BI only allows you to import Pandas DataFrames using Python, so we must convert the dataset using `‘pd.DataFrame’` first.

For example, using the Scikit-Learn library to load the Iris dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()
df = pd.Dataframe(data = data.data, columns= data.feature_names)
print(df)
```

In the next window, select the table called ‘df’ which contains the data. This will now allow you to load this dataset to the data model just like any other data source in Power BI.